# Knitr renders graphic although it shouldnt

Tags: r, histogram, render, knitr

I am using RStudio: Version 1.0.136, and I try to understand why knitr renders the histograms entailed in the commands below. Any help is appreciated.

```
min_ct<-as.numeric(min(hist(myfdata[myfdata$slope>low & myfdata$slope<up, ]$dy, breaks = bi)$counts))
```

Screenshot of 4 rendered graphics, which are not explicitly generated.

[image]

Comment: Calling `hist` causes a histogram to be rendered even if you assign the output to a variable. In the console try `x = hist(rnorm(100))`. What gets saved to the variable is a list with the data used to generate the histogram, but the histogram is still printed.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a way to suppress that the graphics are rendered or a different to get the values of a histogram? I am generating a shiny document (rmd) and all graphics are rendered. I could distribute the code in different chunks and disable the output, but that isn't nice and clean, I guess.

Comment: Yes, use the `cut` function to create the bins, then use `table` to count number of values by bin. For example, `table(cut(rnorm(100), breaks=seq(-3,3,0.1)))`. `cut` has several options that affect how is assigns bins, so take a look at the help (`?cut`) for more info. In particular, take note of the `right`, `include.lowest`, and `labels` arguments.

Comment: Where is the button for marking my question as answered? Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a `knitr` issue. Calling `hist` causes a histogram to be rendered even if you assign the output to a variable. In the console try `x = hist(rnorm(100))`. What gets saved to the variable is a list with the data used to generate the histogram, but the histogram is still printed.

To create bins without printing a histogram, use the `cut` function to create the bins, then use `table` to count number of values by bin. For example, `table(cut(rnorm(100), breaks=seq(-3,3,0.5)))`.

`cut` has options that affect how it assigns bins, so take a look at the help (`?cut`) for more info. In particular, take note of the `right` and `include.lowest` arguments.

Comment: There is also the odd method of calling hist(data, plot=FALSE)